Save all image or photo from attachment attribute table from ArcMap
How to save/export all image from attachment attribute table ArcMap, not save one by one?


If you have access to ArcGIS Pro there is a community toolbox available called Export Attachments Toolbox.  See https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-blog/export-attachments-toolbox/ba-p/1022018

It looks like it (or something similar) has been now incorporated into ArcGIS Pro as a standard toolbox.  See https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/export-attachments.htm
